# find the path with a recursive function with python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create this function that will help me to look into the list of friend and the friends or the friends' lists in order to know how many steps or list of friends I should look for to find the consecutive user in my list of `early_adopters`.

What I have so far:

```
early_adopter = ['2347507100',
                  '1353186810',
                  '897960223662424064']

#distances between early adopters
def get_distance(usr1, usr2):
  follower_list=[]
  path = 0
  for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr1).items(4):
      follower_list.append(user.id)
  if usr2 in follower_list:
    path =+ 1
    return path
  elif usr2 not in follower_list: 
    #repeat the same step above but this time with the user of the follower list, and this will count another step in the path, I want to repeat this process 3 times.
  else:
    return 0


dist = [get_distance(early_adopter[i], early_adopter[i+1]) for i in range(len(early_adopter)-1)]
dist
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I want to get for example, between user1 and user2 in `early_adopters` if user2 is in the first search of follower the output will be 1, if not it will look into the second list (the friends of the friends) so if the user2 is in this new list, the output will be 2, if not it will repeat again until 3 times, if this is not in the 3rd list, the output will be 0. This means the path between the user1 and user2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wrote sometimes user2 and sometimes usr2;

Then you have

1. to loop on follower_list items
2. to increment only if you found a match
3. to limit to 3 depth.

Here is an idea of what you could do :

```
def get_distance(usr1, usr2):
    get_distance_with_depth(usr1, usr2, 0)
    
def get_distance_with_depth(usr1, usr2, depth): // inseert depth in reccursion
    if depth==3:
        return 0
    follower_list=[]
    path = 0
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, user_id = usr1).items(4):
      follower_list.append(user.id)
    if usr2 in follower_list:
        path =+ 1
        return path
    else: //usr2 not in follower_list
        for subuser in follower_list: // loop on subusers
            distance = get_distance_with_depth(subuser, usr2, depth+1)
            if distance != 0: // found a match
                return distance+1 // add +1 only if you find a match
            // if not found, go on looping
        // if reaching here, no match was found
        return 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! when you mentioned two functions at the beginning do you mean that I have to choose one of them

Comment: no, you have to define the two. the first function calls the second, with a depth of 0.

Comment: actually, you might use a unique function, if you use depth the other way:
1. you start with depth 3 
2. when calling again, you decrease depth (depth-1) .
3. you stop when depth equals 0


This way, you don't have to hardcode the depth in the reccursive function, so you can change depth whenever you want using the same function